# How to write into Sqlite Database after deployment

Tags: winforms, sqlite, deployment

I created a setup with Wix toolset to deploy a Winform application that has an SQLite database. The issue I have is that I cannot write into the database and the inner exception says "***Attempt to write to ReadOnly Database***".

I have searched Stack Overflow and the problem appears to be with Root folder access. I saw an option that one can include an executable to allow access to the Database as an administrator.

Can anyone show me how this is done?

Thanks in advance.